# Upload file to drive using ajax and google app script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a code to upload file(image) to google drive using **app script**.
Please go through the code. 
I'm not able to get the file back from the request.parameters. I tried using formData but it didn't work either.

I get following errors:

 the file object received from request parameters is of type string though processData is false 
or 
Refused to execute script from 'app script url' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

```js
// Google App Script
function doPost(request) {
    
    var result;
    // get folder from the drive
   try {
    var dropbox = "tdsd";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var parmKeys = Object.keys(request.parameters);
    Logger.log(parmKeys);
    //get file
    var blob = request.parameters.file;
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
       
    result = {
      status: 'success',
      id: file.getId(),
      url: file.getUrl(),
      }
    
    } catch (error) {
    
      result = {status: 'error', error: error, boo: parmKeys, level: '8'};
    }
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    request.parameters.prefix + '(' + JSON.stringify(result) + ')')
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Your name.." id="myName">
  <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="storeImage();">
</form>

<script>
function storeImage() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var myName = document.getElementById('myName').value;
  var file = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];

  $.ajax({
    url: 'Google_Script_Url?prefix=JsonpCallback',
    method: 'POST',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      file: file
    },
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    mimeType: 'application/javascript',
    success: function(results) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    },
    error: function(results) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I reproduced your error message, but I don't know what it means.  I'm guessing that maybe Google put something in their code that is stopping the POST request.  You can use `google.script.run.serverFunctionName()` to send data to the server.  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)  I'd suggest using that instead of the AJAX request.

Comment: @SandyGood , I cannot use google.script.run.serverFunctionName() function, since I need to use the app script url in my website and unfortunately, google does not allow users to use the app script url in an iframe.

Comment: Okay, so the AJAX request is not in an Apps Script HTML Service, or a Google Site?  I didn't try it from a regular website.

Comment: @RicK hey, can i know your solution? i have the same problem with you, can't upload file using google app script from regular website with AJAX/Fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your ajax request

- jsonp is a GET request not POST, is jsonp used to get around Same Origin Policy?
- File uploads are done via POST requests not jsonp

The basic way to upload a file via ajax is to use a FormData object

```
  var myName = document.getElementById('myName').value;
  var file = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append(myName, file);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Google_Script_Url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success: function(results) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    },
    error: function(results) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  });
```